# How to "skip" a task in rake

Tags: ruby, rake

When building files with `rake`, the build system is smart enough to tell whether or not it needs to actually run a `task` if e.g. the file already exists and the dependencies are not more recent.

Is there a standard way to skip other tasks? I'm thinking of something maybe like

```
task :containers do
  sh "docker-composer up"
end

# the following doesn't exist
task :containers, if: `docker ps | grep mycontainer`.empty?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `next` keyword to "skip out" of a task whenever you want, e.g.

```
task :containers do
  next if `docker ps | grep mycontainer`.empty?
  sh "docker-composer up"
end
```

and that won't interrupt the flow of other tasks in the queue.

Alternatively, you could just wrap your task code in an `if` statement inside the task definition, and maybe print something out if the condition fails.